# Parse json array in jquery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am new to JSON, and I am trying to get the JSON response and then parse it in jquery.

Here is my sample code,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'ajax-script.php',
    data: {
        TERMINAL_CODE: value
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#arrivals').html(data.Success);
        //alert(data.length);
    }
});
```

**ajax-script.php**

```
$code = $_GET['TERMINAL_CODE'];

$jsonData = '{"Success" : true ,"Response":  [{
    "TERMINAL_CODE": 16,
    "TERMINAL_NAME": "FAISALABAD"
}, {
    "TERMINAL_CODE": 17,
    "TERMINAL_NAME": "JHANG"
}, {
    "TERMINAL_CODE": 1,
    "TERMINAL_NAME": "LAHORE"
}, {
    "TERMINAL_CODE": 5,
    "TERMINAL_NAME": "MULTAN"
}, {
    "TERMINAL_CODE": 23,
    "TERMINAL_NAME": "NOWSHERA"
}, {
    "TERMINAL_CODE": 25,
    "TERMINAL_NAME": "PESHAWAR"
}, {
    "TERMINAL_CODE": 22,
    "TERMINAL_NAME": "RAWALPINDI"
}, {
    "TERMINAL_CODE": 31,
    "TERMINAL_NAME": "SIALKOT"
}]
}
';

echo $jsonData;
```

This code gives me the complete array in **arrivals div**, But i need `TERMINAL_CODE` and `TERMINAL_NAME` separately?
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use JSON.parse(data) to convert it to a JS object. Then you can reference the properties of each object in the response array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse()` to parse the json first and then iterate over the data as

```
var json = {"Success" : true ,"Response": 
[{"TERMINAL_CODE":16,"TERMINAL_NAME":"FAISALABAD"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":17,"TERMINAL_NAME":"JHANG"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":1,"TERMINAL_NAME":"LAHORE"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":5,"TERMINAL_NAME":"MULTAN"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":23,"TERMINAL_NAME":"NOWSHERA"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":25,"TERMINAL_NAME":"PESHAWAR"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":22,"TERMINAL_NAME":"RAWALPINDI"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":31,"TERMINAL_NAME":"SIALKOT"}]};

$.each(json.Response, function(i, v) {
  var str = "<div>TERMINAL CODE " + v.TERMINAL_CODE + "</div>"
    $('#push').append(str);
  var str1 = "<div>TERMINAL NAME " + v.TERMINAL_NAME + "</div>"
  $('#push').append(str1);


})
```

**SNIPPET**

```js
var json = {"Success" : true ,"Response": 
[{"TERMINAL_CODE":16,"TERMINAL_NAME":"FAISALABAD"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":17,"TERMINAL_NAME":"JHANG"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":1,"TERMINAL_NAME":"LAHORE"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":5,"TERMINAL_NAME":"MULTAN"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":23,"TERMINAL_NAME":"NOWSHERA"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":25,"TERMINAL_NAME":"PESHAWAR"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":22,"TERMINAL_NAME":"RAWALPINDI"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":31,"TERMINAL_NAME":"SIALKOT"}]};

$.each(json.Response, function(i, v) {
  var str = "<div>TERMINAL CODE " + v.TERMINAL_CODE + "</div>"
 $('#push').append(str);
  var str1 = "<div>TERMINAL NAME " + v.TERMINAL_NAME + "</div>"
  $('#push').append(str1);
  

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="push">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = {
 "Success": true,
 "Response": [{
  "TERMINAL_CODE": 16,
  "TERMINAL_NAME": "FAISALABAD"
 }, {
  "TERMINAL_CODE": 17,
  "TERMINAL_NAME": "JHANG"
 }, {
  "TERMINAL_CODE": 1,
  "TERMINAL_NAME": "LAHORE"
 }, {
  "TERMINAL_CODE": 5,
  "TERMINAL_NAME": "MULTAN"
 }, {
  "TERMINAL_CODE": 23,
  "TERMINAL_NAME": "NOWSHERA"
 }, {
  "TERMINAL_CODE": 25,
  "TERMINAL_NAME": "PESHAWAR"
 }, {
  "TERMINAL_CODE": 22,
  "TERMINAL_NAME": "RAWALPINDI"
 }, {
  "TERMINAL_CODE": 31,
  "TERMINAL_NAME": "SIALKOT"
 }]
}

data = data.Response
$.each(data, function(i,v){
console.log(v.TERMINAL_NAME)
console.log(v.TERMINAL_CODE)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the data

> Description: Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for()` or `each()` method. I am suggesting to use `getJSON()` method for load JSON data from server.

```
$.getJSON('ajax-script.php'{TERMINAL_CODE: value}).done(function(data) {
              $('#arrivals').html(data.Success);
              $.each(data.Response, function( i, item ){
                 console.log(item .TERMINAL_NAME)
                 console.log(item .TERMINAL_CODE)
              })
              //alert(data.length);
            }
      });
```

Sample

```js
var data = {
 "Success": true,
 "Response": [{
  "TERMINAL_CODE": 16,
  "TERMINAL_NAME": "FAISALABAD"
 }, {
  "TERMINAL_CODE": 17,
  "TERMINAL_NAME": "JHANG"
 }, {
  "TERMINAL_CODE": 1,
  "TERMINAL_NAME": "LAHORE"
 }, {
  "TERMINAL_CODE": 5,
  "TERMINAL_NAME": "MULTAN"
 }, {
  "TERMINAL_CODE": 23,
  "TERMINAL_NAME": "NOWSHERA"
 }, {
  "TERMINAL_CODE": 25,
  "TERMINAL_NAME": "PESHAWAR"
 }, {
  "TERMINAL_CODE": 22,
  "TERMINAL_NAME": "RAWALPINDI"
 }, {
  "TERMINAL_CODE": 31,
  "TERMINAL_NAME": "SIALKOT"
 }]
} 

terminal_codes=[];
$.each(data.Response, function( i, item ){
                     console.log(item .TERMINAL_NAME)
                     console.log(item .TERMINAL_CODE);
                      terminal_codes.push(item .TERMINAL_CODE);
                  });

$('#arrivals').html(terminal_codes.join(","));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="arrivals"></div>
```

Check examples of [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: I have used this above console.log  **$('#arrivals').html(item.TERMINAL_CODE);**  but it gives me only the last terminal code?

Comment: You are overriting #arrivals html all time in loop so you  getting only last element value. you need to do something like this.. as I have added in code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

To get response as `json` we need to pass dataType as json.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'ajax-script.php',
  dataType:'json',
  data: { TERMINAL_CODE: value},
  success: function(data) {    
   for (i in data.Response) {
    var row = data.Response[i];
    $('#arrivals').append('TERMINAL_CODE : ' + row.TERMINAL_CODE +',TERMINAL_NAME:'+ row.TERMINAL_NAME+'<br/>');
   }                  
  }
 });  
});   
</script>
```

```html
<div id="arrivals"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes your ajax-script.php is correct, I think it will be better to organize data something differently and output string will be same and suggest to change following code in another snippet,

```
$code = $_GET['TERMINAL_CODE'];

$jsonData = '{"Success" : true ,"Response": 
[{"TERMINAL_CODE":16,"TERMINAL_NAME":"FAISALABAD"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":17,"TERMINAL_NAME":"JHANG"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":1,"TERMINAL_NAME":"LAHORE"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":5,"TERMINAL_NAME":"MULTAN"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":23,"TERMINAL_NAME":"NOWSHERA"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":25,"TERMINAL_NAME":"PESHAWAR"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":22,"TERMINAL_NAME":"RAWALPINDI"},
{"TERMINAL_CODE":31,"TERMINAL_NAME":"SIALKOT"}]}';

echo $jsonData;
```

to

```
$code = $_GET['TERMINAL_CODE'];
$jsonData = array('success' =>  true,
                  'Response' => array(
                                  array(
                                    'TERMINAL_CODE'=>16,
                                    'TERMINAL_NAME'='FAISALABAD'
                                   ),
                                   array(
                                    'TERMINAL_CODE'=>17,
                                    'TERMINAL_NAME'='JHANG'
                                   ),
                                   array(
                                    'TERMINAL_CODE'=>1,
                                    'TERMINAL_NAME'='LAHORE'
                                   ),
                                   array(
                                    'TERMINAL_CODE'=>5,
                                    'TERMINAL_NAME'='MULTAN'
                                   ),
                                   array(
                                    'TERMINAL_CODE'=>23,
                                    'TERMINAL_NAME'='NOWSHERA'
                                   ),
                                   array(
                                    'TERMINAL_CODE'=>25,
                                    'TERMINAL_NAME'='PESHAWAR'
                                   ),
                                   array(
                                    'TERMINAL_CODE'=>22,
                                    'TERMINAL_NAME'='RAWALPINDI'
                                   ),
                                   array(
                                    'TERMINAL_CODE'=>31,
                                    'TERMINAL_NAME'='SIALKOT'
                                   ),

                                )
             );

echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

and in ajax-part

```
$.ajax(
     {
       type: "GET",
       url: 'ajax-script.php',
       data: { TERMINAL_CODE: value},
       // add another line here to convert response text i.e data to json format, server will send response text in string to do so,
       dataType : 'json',
       success: function(data) {
                // if you didnot add line dataType: 'json', you can simply convert response text to json object by 
                data = JSON.parse(data); 
                $('#arrivals').html(data.Success);
                //alert(data.length);
            }
        });
```